# Reputation disappeared with no sign / reason why

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Yesterday I got 11 downvotes in a minute (for different posts). As expected, it was fixed a few hours later, but -

Last night I lost 300 reputation, (which may happen of course) but there is no indication why in the Activity / Reputation tabs of my profile. How can I find out why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely your reputation was recalculated. The 11 downvotes in a minute were probably all from the same person, so the system considered it vote fraud and canceled the votes. The person voted on is automatically recalculated when that happens, and usually your rep goes down, since you lose the rep you had from deleted answers (or answers on deleted questions)

Comment: Oh. That's explains it. Thanks!